# Tensorboard export results are not showing trial id in the export files

Tags: tensorflow, export, data-visualization, tensorboard

I am running a bunch of models with learning rate, batch_size, weight decay, and lambda value(used in loss function) hyperparameters in a grid search and training my DNN on these hyperparameters in grid search to understand how each model is learning. As a result, I have around 100+ models which are present in the same run directory used by tensorboard for visualization.

I would like to export the results for these 100+ models to a csv file. While there is an option to get the results in the hparams tab of tensorboard, it doesn't add the trial id column in the export file. This is causing some issue in associating each test result to its trial id, which is quite needed for me. Are there any workarounds to this problem?